# Can We Upgrade the Name and Symbol of ERC20 Token

Tags: ethereum, erc20

Can the Name and Symbol of an ERC20 token be upgraded?

Comment: It depends on your smart contract. Do you have the code of your smart contract?

Comment: Yes its normal erc20 with upgradable openzeppelin

Comment: 1. Create a new token contract with `setNameAndSymbol`. 2. Upgrade 3. set name and symbol

Comment: By upgrading you mean either:
1. Replacing the existing token contract with a newly deployed contract with a different name and symbol?
2. Use the existing token contract - just change the name and symbol values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upgrade the name and symbol of an ERC20 token, you can update the token name and symbol by modifying the smart contract. If you're using OpenZeppelin, you can update the name and symbol in the ERC20 smart contract by modifying the following part: `ERC20("MyToken", "MT")`. [link](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/ethereum-development/smart-contracts/how-to-create-and-deploy-an-erc20-token)

It's also possible to create and deploy an upgradeable ERC20 token using OpenZeppelin and Foundry, which allows for the upgrade of various aspects, including the contract name and symbol. [link](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/ethereum-development/smart-contracts/how-to-create-and-deploy-an-upgradeable-erc20-token)

Comment: Yes but when we upgrade the contract name and symbol are still the same.

So this is not the solution.

Comment: @SohailGhafoor Why did you accept the answer if it is not the solution?